# How to calculate bounds

Tags: react-leaflet

I am trying to use React-leaflet but unable to make boundsOptions work. This is apparently because they only work if we pre-calculate bounds.

How to calculate bounds given certain point and zoom level or radius?

```
const position = [40.706213526877455, -74.0044641494751];
const zoom = 13;

return (<Map ref="leaflet" center={ position } boundsOptions={ { paddingBottomRight: [100, 100] } zoom={ zoom } } />)
```

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the bounds before or after the map renders?  React-Leaflet's code in the <Map> component will not fit the map to bounds unless you send over the `bounds` property.

Comment: @EvanSiroky my solution below calculates it before rendering, which is optimal because I avoid unwanted animations.

Answer (score 2):

You can use getBounds()

```
this.refs.leaflet.leafletElement.getBounds()
```

Comment: I tried that but I can only get reference to leaflet from `ref` after entire map is rendered. This approach has side effects such as unwanted animations on first pass. I could probably workaround that.

Answer (score 1):

Calculated bounds using `cheap-ruler`, i.e:

```
getBounds(center) {
  const ruler = cheapRuler(center[0], 'meters');
  const bbox = ruler.bufferPoint(center, 100000);
  const p1 = Leaflet.latLng(bbox[0], bbox[1]);
  const p2 = Leaflet.latLng(bbox[2], bbox[3]);

  return Leaflet.latLngBounds(p1, p2);
}
```